# What is the undocumented CNAMEs property in a CloudFront DistributionConfig?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Inside the cloudformation documentation for the `CloudFront` `DistributionConfig` there is a undocumented property called `CNAMEs`, [see documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig-cnames).

```
CNAMEs
  Property description not available.
  Required: No
  Type: Array of String
  Update requires: No interruption
```

I am familiar on how to configure an `A` `RecordSet` as alternate domain for a distibution but I do not understand what- or how the `CNAMEs` property is used.

Can anyone tell what this property is for?

Answer (score 0):

It is a mistake in CF docs. If you check [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDistribution.html#API_CreateDistribution_RequestBody) (CF uses API under hood), there is no such argument as `CNAMEs`.

Comment: Its not only the documentation. The cloudfromation accepts this property. Its a valid cloudformation syntax. I am wondering what happened, if they mixed up the implementation for the Aliases property.